# javascript calling multiple functions simultaneously

Tags: javascript

```
a = function(x) {
    return new Date().getTime();
}

b = function(x) {
    return new Date().getTime();
}

c = function(x,y) {
    return x+' '+y
}

console.log(c(a(),b()));
```

In the above code, functions `a` and `b` are called simultaneously by function `c`. Does function `a` execute first and then function `b`, or do both functions execute simultaneously? It's hard to tell since the time stamps returned are the same.

Comment: The function `c()` does not call either `a()` or `b()`; they're called in preparation for the call to `c()`, and they're called one at a time, left to right.

Comment: They aren't called simultaneously *or* by `c`, the arguments *to* `c` are resolved left-to-right by calling `a` *then* `b`.

Comment: This confusion could of been solved  by not writing this code in the first place `c(a(),b())`. If it's not clear what's happening, don't do it that way. [Good programmers write code that humans can understand.](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Martin_Fowler)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`c(a(),b())` - this is a function invocation expression.

Invocation expressions consist of following parts:

- function expression that identifies the function that is to be called.
- opening parenthesis.
- comma-separated list of zero or more argument expressions.
- closing parenthesis.

When function invocation expression is evaluated, function expression is evaluated first and then the argument expressions, if there are any, are evaluated (from left to right) to produce values that are to be passed to the function that is being called.

`c(a(),b())` is evaluated as:

1. First of all, identifier `c` is evaluated. If `c` wasn't defined, javascript would have thrown a `ReferenceError`.
2. Since in this case, `c` is a function, so argument expressions are evaluated from left to right.
3. First `a()` is evaluated which itself is an invocation expression. So `a` is evaluated first and since there are no arguments, function `a` is invoked and the body of the function `a` executes. Since `a` returns `new Date().getTime()`, it becomes the value of `a()` invocation expression.
4. After that `b()` is evaluated in the same way as `a()` is evaluated.
5. Finally, `c()` is called with the return values of `a()` and `b()` as its arguments. If `c` wasn't a function, javascript would have thrown a `TypeError`.

Comment: Actually it only fails at step 1 if `c` is not defined, with a `ReferenceError`. If `c` is defined, the arguments are evaluated *before* trying to invoke it with those values, so if it's not actually callable you only find out with a `TypeError `around step 5.

Comment: If you do e.g. `"foo"((function () { throw new Error("whoops!"); })())` you'll see the uncaught `whoops!` error, *not* a TypeError that a string isn't callable.

Comment: @jonrsharpe that seems to verify what you are saying but it also contradicts what David Flanagan, author of `Javascript: The Definitive Guide`, says about [Invocation Expressions](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/javascript-the-definitive/9781449393854/ch04s05.html#:~:text=An%20invocation%20expression%20is%20JavaScript's,the%20function%20to%20be%20called.) in his book. If you read the fourth line, it says that function expression is evaluated before argument expressions.

Comment: No, I don't think that's contradictory. That also says that the TypeError would be *after* the argument values are evaluated.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ok, so if i understand what you are saying and what david says in his book,  is that `TypeError` is thrown _only after_ evaluating the argument expressions but function expression itself is evaluated before argument expressions, right?

Comment: Correct - if `c` couldn't be resolved to a value at all that would error *before* the arguments are evaluated, but if it was resolved to a value that isn't callable that would error *after* the arguments are evaluated.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you for the clarification :) Code in your second comment really had me confused about my understanding of invocation expressions :P

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is always running in one Thread, so they are called after one another.

The reason why the timestamp is the same is because the clock of your computer (or the client computer) has only a specific resolution. I have something of `16ms` in mind which is definitively bigger than the call to the two functions.

Anyway I'm not exactly sure what function is called first I would assume `a` and than `b`, but this can be dependent to the Javascript interpreter.